# New to programming. Trying to make a program in C that prints even numbers till 10. Can't figure out the logic error

Tags: c, logic

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int n=10;

    for(int a=n;a>=1;a++)  //for bringing out numbers from 1-10
    {
       int e=a%2; //int e to figure out if the number is even(divisible by 2)
       if(e==0)
        printf("%d\n",a); //printing the even numbers
    }
}
```

I am new to programming. Learning C. 
Here I am trying to make a program that prints even numbers till 10. Executing this code leads to endless even numbers starting from 10.

Can't seem to figure out the logic error here. Some help, please?

Comment: for(int a=n;a>=1;a--) or for(int a=1;a<=n;a++)

Comment: @NafisIslam that prints it in descending order

Comment: Why not `a+=2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic for the for loop is not correct.

```
int n = 10;

for(int a = 0; a <= n; a++) {
    if(a%2==0){
        printf(a);
    }
}
```

Notice that this is stating at 0, because in CS almost all the time the count starts at 0.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop will never end, it should be:

```
for(int a = 1; a <= 10; a++)
```

The entire program should be like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{ 
  for(int a = 1; a <= 10; a++)  //for bringing out numbers from 1-10    
    {
      int e = a % 2; //int e to figure out if the number is even(divisible by 2)
      if(e == 0)
        printf("%d\n", a); //printing the even numbers
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2
4
6
8
10
```